# How to iterate a value evenly and return the output it in one go

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to work a given set of parameters that define the minimum value and maximum value `(minNumber, maxNumber)`.  Basically, I want to take my `minNumber`, if it isn't even, find the nearest even number (if 5, use 6) and incremented it by 2 `(6, 8, 10, ... maxNumber)` until it is `<= maxNumber`.  For example, if my `minNumber = 4` and `maxNumber = 21`, my `output = 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20`

This is my last attempt:

```
function evenNumbers(minNumber, maxNumber){
  i = 0;
  output = "" + minNumber + ", " + minNumber * i
  if(minNumber % 2 == 0){
    for (i = 2; i <= maxNumber; i+2){
      output += ", " + minNumber * i
    }
  }
  return output
}
```

Using this pre-defined set of parameters:

```
console.log('evenNumbers(4,13) returns: ' + evenNumbers(4, 13));
console.log('evenNumbers(3,10) returns: ' + evenNumbers(3, 10));
console.log('evenNumbers(8,21) returns: ' + evenNumbers(8, 21));
console.log('\n');
```

But now I'm getting an "out of memory" error.  This is my desired output:

[image]

Comment: please define all variables in advance. some semicolons does not hurt either.

Comment: In your for loop, you are not assigning the step back to variable.. `for (i = 2; i <= maxNumber; i += 2)` should fix your problem.

Comment: Typo! change this `i+2` to this `i+=2`.  However, this doesn't solve the current behavior of your function.

Comment: You're right.  And boy is scratchpad an annoying app.

Comment: Feel free to delete this question, as it is getting a lot of "answers" which are not meaningful any more.

Comment: Doesn't allow me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And just for the fun of it... here's a simpler version:

```
<script>

function evenNumbers2(minNumber, maxNumber){
  var output = "";

  for (var i = minNumber; i <= maxNumber; i++)
  {
     if (i % 2 == 0)
     {
        output += ", " + i;
     }
  }

  return output.substring(2,999);
}

console.log('evenNumbers2(4,13) returns: ' + evenNumbers2(4, 13));
console.log('evenNumbers2(3,10) returns: ' + evenNumbers2(3, 10));
console.log('evenNumbers2(8,21) returns: ' + evenNumbers2(8, 21));


</script>
```

Comment: It worked.  Thank you, sir.  I've accepted your answer and given you an upvote.  If you think my question was well asked, do you mind upvoting me?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<script>

function evenNumbers(minNumber, maxNumber){

  if(minNumber % 2 != 0){ minNumber++ }
  var output = "" + minNumber ;

  for (var i = minNumber + 2; i <= maxNumber; i = i + 2)
  {
     output += ", " + i;
  }

  return output
}

console.log('evenNumbers(4,13) returns: ' + evenNumbers(4, 13));
console.log('evenNumbers(3,10) returns: ' + evenNumbers(3, 10));
console.log('evenNumbers(8,21) returns: ' + evenNumbers(8, 21));

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be it:

```
function evenNumbers(minNumber, maxNumber){
  var output = "";
  if(minNumber % 2 != 0){
    output = minNumber + 1;
    for (i = minNumber+3; i <= maxNumber; i+=2){
      output += ", " + i;
    }
  }
  else{
    output = minNumber;
    for (i = minNumber+2; i <= maxNumber; i+=2){
      output += ", " + i;
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

You forgot the "=" while updating the i value.

I also tried to clean up a bit the function.

Btw, if(x % 2 == 0) is true it means that x is even, if it is !=0 it is odd.

Comment: Its not it.  The output of your function is literally empty.

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: Oh I missunderstood, I understood the only case you needed was with odd numbers, you just need to add a case with even, I will add it now.

Comment: try it now, I've added both the even and odd case

Answer (score -1):

The function for getting the array of even numbers in the range

```
function even(a, b) {
    var a = (a + 1) & 0xfffffffe;
    var r = [];
    for (; a <= b; a += 2) {
        r.push(a);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Mate can you make this relevant to the example given above?

Answer (score -1):

```
function evenNumbers(minNumber, maxNumber) {
  # Check if even; add 1 to number if not
  if (minNumber % 2 != 0) {
    minNumber++
  }
  var arr = []
  # Iterate through numbers, incrementing minNumber
  # and creating array of output
  while (minNumber <= maxNumber) {
    arr.push(minNumber);
    minNumber += 2;
  }
  # return array formatted as string with commas
  return arr.join(',');
}
```

Comment: if you're going to downvote, can you please explain why?